# R: How can I disable truncation of listing of package functions?

Tags: r

How can I list all of the results that used to occur when typing `packageName<tab>`, i.e. the full list offered via auto-completion?  In R 2.15.0, I get the following for `Matrix::<tab>`:

```
> library(Matrix)
> Matrix::
Matrix::.__C__abIndex               Matrix::.__C__atomicVector          Matrix::.__C__BunchKaufman          Matrix::.__C__CHMfactor             Matrix::.__C__CHMsimpl              
Matrix::.__C__CHMsuper              Matrix::.__C__Cholesky              Matrix::.__C__CholeskyFactorization Matrix::.__C__compMatrix            Matrix::.__C__corMatrix             
Matrix::.__C__CsparseMatrix         Matrix::.__C__dCHMsimpl             Matrix::.__C__dCHMsuper             Matrix::.__C__ddenseMatrix          Matrix::.__C__ddiMatrix             
Matrix::.__C__denseLU               Matrix::.__C__denseMatrix           Matrix::.__C__dgCMatrix             Matrix::.__C__dgeMatrix             Matrix::.__C__dgRMatrix             
Matrix::.__C__dgTMatrix             Matrix::.__C__diagonalMatrix        Matrix::.__C__dMatrix               Matrix::.__C__dpoMatrix             Matrix::.__C__dppMatrix             
Matrix::.__C__dsCMatrix             Matrix::.__C__dsparseMatrix         Matrix::.__C__dsparseVector         Matrix::.__C__dspMatrix             Matrix::.__C__dsRMatrix             
Matrix::.__C__dsTMatrix             Matrix::.__C__dsyMatrix             Matrix::.__C__dtCMatrix             Matrix::.__C__dtpMatrix             Matrix::.__C__dtrMatrix             
Matrix::.__C__dtRMatrix             Matrix::.__C__dtTMatrix             Matrix::.__C__generalMatrix         Matrix::.__C__iMatrix               Matrix::.__C__index                 
Matrix::.__C__isparseVector         Matrix::.__C__ldenseMatrix          Matrix::.__C__ldiMatrix             Matrix::.__C__lgCMatrix             Matrix::.__C__lgeMatrix             
Matrix::.__C__lgRMatrix             Matrix::.__C__lgTMatrix             Matrix::.__C__lMatrix               Matrix::.__C__lsCMatrix             Matrix::.__C__lsparseMatrix         

[...truncated]
```

That `[...truncated]` message is irritating and I want to produce the full listing.  Which option/flag/knob/configuration/incantation do I need to invoke in order to avoid the truncation?  I have this impression that I used to see the full list, but not anymore - perhaps that was on a different OS (e.g. Linux).

I know that `ls("package:Matrix")` is one useful approach, but it is not the same as setting an option, and the list is different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, on Windows, it looks like this behavior is hard-wired into the `C` code used to construct the console.  So the answer seems to be that "no, you can't disable it" (at least not without modifying the sources and then recompiling R from scratch).

Here are the relevant lines from `$RHOME/src/gnuwin32/console.c`:

```
909 static void performCompletion(control c)
910 {
911    ConsoleData p = getdata(c);
912    int i, alen, alen2, max_show = 10, cursor_position = p->c - prompt_wid;
    ...
    ...
1001      if (alen > max_show)
1002      consolewrites(c, "\n[...truncated]\n");
```

You are correct that on some other platforms, all of the results *are* printed out. (I often use Emacs, for instance, and it pops all results of tab completion up in a separate buffer).

As an interesting side note, `rcompgen`, the backend that actually performs the tab-completion (as opposed to printing results to the console) does always *find* all completions. It's just that Windows doesn't then print them out for us to see.

You can verify that this happens even on Windows by typing:

```
library(Matrix)
Matrix::
## Then type <TAB> <TAB>
## Then type <RET>
rc.status()      ## Careful not to use tab-completion to complete rc.status !
matches <- rc.status()$comps
length(matches)  # -> 288
matches          # -> lots of symbols starting with 'Matrix::'
```

For more details about about the backend, and the functions and options that control its behavior, see [`?rcompgen`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/rcompgen.html).

Comment: I am sold that this is the correct answer.  I suspect that I was used to the auto-complete behavior on Linux, and that nothing has changed on Windows.  I hope the R on Windows UI decision is not propagated to R on other platforms.  Your insights on the other components are fantastic, thanks!